# Hibernate: What is the correct way to update collection of an entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to optimize our hibernate application. In many places, while add/updating a collection of an entity, we are clearing it first, and then add all of them again from the input. I feel somehow, there should be a better way but could not found yet.

How do you do in your applications.?

Answer (score 0):

I guess with collection, you mean the "many" side of an `@OneToMany` relationship.

In this case, you can specify the value `orphanRemoval` in the `@OneToMany` annotation to the foreign reference in the owning class:

```
public class Parent {

    // ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "whatever", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Child> children;  

}
```

`orphanRemoval` will instruct Hibernate to delete all existing child entities that have been removed from the collection when the parent entity is persisted.

Comment: We have set orphanRemoval=true, but why we need to delete all the entries and add it back. Is it the correct way? In this case, even if there is no change, we will clear and add it back. Isn't there any way to see if we need to update or insert efficiently?

Comment: your don't have to remove and re-add them. Cascade. All will also update the children.